# Why does my Nest.js application only read the .env file instead of other environment configuration files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Additional information: I recreated the project using Nest CLI, and with the same code, the problem was not reproduced. Therefore, I suspect that the issue is related to NX CLI. Has anyone used NX to generate a Nest.js project? Its official website is [https://nx.dev/."](https://nx.dev/.%22)

I'm using the Nest.js framework to develop an application, and I've configured multiple environment files such as ".env.production", ".env.development.local", etc. according to the official documentation. However, in actual development, I noticed that my application only reads the settings from the ".env" file and ignores all other files.

What could be causing this issue? Have I missed any necessary steps or configurations? How can I resolve this problem and get my application to correctly read the settings from other environment files? Thank you very much for your help!

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: ['.env.development.local', '.env.production', '.env'],
      isGlobal: true,
      cache: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my code for calling ConfigService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService
  ) {}
  async getToken() {
    console.log(this.configService.get('TOKEN'));
  }
}
```

My configuration file looks like this:

```
// .env.development.local
TOKEN=8cd8cd57cfcfe57cfcfe
```

According to the official documentation at https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration, I've made several modifications and tried restarting many times, but I still can't get the .env.development.local file to be read correctly. It's only reading the .env file, which makes my environment configuration very limited!

Comment: can you show us the content of those dot env files? just the keys, of course

Comment: Sure, the content of my environment configuration file looks like TOKEN=xxxxxxx

Comment: those file have same key?? I guess you want to change .env by running environment..

Comment: I want to modify the priority of Nest.js reading environment variables, where if the .env.development.local file is present, it should be read first.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the root cause of the problem. It turns out that the NX CLI modified the way the Nest program reads environment variables, which caused the issue. According to the official website at [nx docs](https://nx.dev/recipes/environment-variables/define-environment-variables), I have to say that the invasive behavior of the NX CLI almost invalidated the Nest/config. I hope that anyone who encounters the same problem can resolve it.

Comment: any solution i got the same issue